# ¿Algun tipo de desbordamiento Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

estaba realizando el problema #2 de Proyecto Euler y de repente note que cuando las cantidades numericas eran altas se mostraban numeros extraños negativos y positivos,en c++ tambien me pasaba lo mismo,alguien conoce porque se da esto ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    //   c=a+b;
   int a=1,b=2,c=0;
   for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
   {

   c=a+b;
   a=b;
   b=c;

       System.out.println(c);

   }


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que si es desbordamiento.  Intenta con `long` en lugar de `int` para confirmar

Comment: Sin duda. He cambiado de `int` a  `double` y ya no ocurre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que los números generados son demasiado grandes para ser guardados en un `int` o en un `long`.

**Cuando dices:**

```
// int
a = 1134903170;
b = 1836311903;
resultado = 2,971,215,073;

// long
a = 4660046610375530309;
b = 7540113804746346429;
resultado = 1.22001604151e+19; // Muy largo para mostrar
```

Ambos resultados son muy grandes y no caben dentro de un `int` o un `long`.

**Recordar que:**

```
          width                     minimum                         maximum

SIGNED
byte:     8 bit                        -128                            +127
short:   16 bit                     -32 768                         +32 767
int:     32 bit              -2 147 483 648                  +2 147 483 647
long:    64 bit  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808      +9 223 372 036 854 775 807
```

Para resolver tu problema necesitas usar **BigInteger**. Aquí la Documentación Oficial: [Class BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

**Código:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger a = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger c = new BigInteger("0");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

            c = a.add(b); // Método para la suma
            a = b;
            b = c;

            System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + a);

        }
    }
```

Con esto, los números largos serán guardados correctamente y no tendrás números negativos o mal calculados.

Saludos.